# Linux command to preserve timestamp while copying files from FTP

Tags: linux

I have copied some files from a Windows machine to a Linux machine via FTP. But the time stamp is not preserved. Is there any Linux command to preserve the time stamp while copying files from FTP?

Comment: No, there isn't. Better to use tools such as rsync for copying files and preserve timestamp, for example, rsync -av /src/ /dest/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's the old implementation of MFMT that allows that. It's not compliant with RFC though.

Comment: Please define which RFC you are referring to.